# how to trigger multi event in same level multi div overlap area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i define a event in same level div,but i can't trigger the event with div between multi different div overlap area,just one of them triggered,how to trigger these same level div events by overlap area?
the example code like this

```js
    function Triggered(e){
        console.log(event.target.id);// 
    }
```

```css
    .S{
        position: absolute;
        width: 99px;
        height: 99px;
        opacity: .7;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="1" style="background-color:blue;left: 50%;top:50%" onclick="Triggered()"  class="S"></div>
    <div id="2" style="background-color:red;left: 50%;top:50%;transform: translate(-25%,-50%);"  onclick="Triggered()"  class="S"></div>
    <div id="3" style="background-color:green;left: 50%;top:50%;transform: translate(-50px,0);"  onclick="Triggered()"  class="S"></div>
</body>
```

**(ps: it's use for slove the li sort question,when li A over another li B,the mouseover event in B can't  trigger,just trigger A,so i need a solution for slove multi same level div event triggered in overlap area,pointer-events：none it's not helpful,i need trigger multi event in overlap area not one)**

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to detect click event for your three divs, even when they overlap each other. Since your tags are defined at the same level, you cannot use event bubbling or capturing to handle click at different levels like we do with nested tags.

When user clicks, try calling function `document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)` to get all elements underneath the mouse pointer.

```js
function Triggered(e) {
  var clickedElements = [];
  document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.classList.contains('S')) {
      clickedElements.push(element.id);
    }
  });
  console.log(clickedElements);
}
```

```css
.S {
  position: absolute;
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="Triggered()">
  <div id="blue" style="background-color:blue;left: 50%;top:15%" class="S"></div>
  <div id="red" style="background-color:red;left: 50%;top:15%;transform: translate(-25%,-50%);" class="S"></div>
  <div id="green" style="background-color:green;left: 50%;top:15%;transform: translate(-50px,0);" class="S"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i more prefer some day html extends the attribute like "extends" of pointer-events to improve the same level div pointer event detection,it seems more pithy in these case

Answer (score 0):

I started out with an approach along the lines of:

```
if (e.target.style.getPropertyValue('pointer-events') !== 'none') {

  console.log(e.target.id);
}

else {

  e.target.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'none');
  e.target.dispatchEvent('click');
  e.target.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
}
```

But quickly learned that the `pointer-events` property **does not work** with computational clicks.

---

This is my final solution (ultimately very similar to the solution provided by `@derloopkat`, above, so credit should go to that answer, not this one).

**Working Example:**

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
const div3 = document.getElementById('div3');

const triggered = (e) => {
 
  // GET MOUSE POSITION
  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;
  
  // GET STACKED ELEMENTS
  const stackedElements = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y);
  
  // BUILD ARRAY OF TARGET ELEMENTS
  const targetElements = [];

  for (let stackedElement of stackedElements) {
  
    if (stackedElement.classList.contains('s')) {
      targetElements.push(stackedElement);
    }
  }
  
  // LOG IDS OF TARGET ELEMENTS
  for (let targetElement of targetElements) {
  
    console.log(targetElement.id);
  }
}

div1.addEventListener('click', triggered, true);
div2.addEventListener('click', triggered, true);
div3.addEventListener('click', triggered, true);
```

```css
.s {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  opacity: .7;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(-25%, -50%);
}

#div3 {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translate(-50px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="s"></div>
<div id="div2" class="s"></div>
<div id="div3" class="s"></div>
```